# Why does this string starts with a slash get an incompatible error in the nested mapped types?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I got an incompatible error in this code below.

```
type Test = { 
  [slasher in `/${string}`]: {
    [method in 'POST' | 'GET']: {
      parameter: unknown
    }
  }
}

type ExtendedTest = { 
  '/slash': {
    'POST': {
      parameter: unknown
    }
  }
}

const Tester = <T extends Test>() => {
  console.log()
}

Tester<ExtendedTest>()
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Type 'ExtendedTest' does not satisfy the constraint 'Test'.
# Property ''/slash'' is incompatible with index signature.
```

If it's not nested or specify "slash" string(without heading slash), this problem won't occur.
Does the string starts with a slash has special meanings, is it wrong index signature or some defeats in the structure of this mapped types?

Comment: If I remove both slashes [it has the same error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8oCgpQNrwBsBDeACwgCcoBLAOygAMASNRCugcwF8GBdALnTYceALYRgpAPYATGvQDkABQDyAZRgKoAHygKA4gFFNAoSJFgiFIuOCVBAV1oBrWlIDutYTi7DfvzFBIKEMADztaGQgZOEQUdCwcBUISUgVBNG89VQ10s3MoS2tbeygnVw8vc18fTACAYylaONi7KlQAHhgoCHCISPhYBGAAPgAKAEoUEfzG5qkCCAA6AikOSbrMTFbKDrCIqJjh8YmgA), that the `'GET'` field is required. In both cases the error is resolved by adding the `'GET'` property

Comment: Thanks, I can also stop the error by adding a 'GET' property. It means when the error didn't occurred, "slash" weren't recognized as index of Test type, right? And I have another question that in nested mapped types, must parent indexes (in this case, `/${string}`) have all patterns of children indexes(`'POST' | 'GET'`)'?